# How to implement variable velocity in my rhythm game

Tags: c#

I have a vertical scrolling rhythm game, here is the commented code of the basic logic of the game neccesary to understand the question

```
int scrollSpeed = 500 //time in ms that take the note to get from the top to the bottom
float currentTime = 0 //time in ms of the song playing
List<int> noteTimings = new List() //List of the time in ms that the player should hit them, sorted in ascending order

for(i=0; i<noteTimings.Count; i++) {
    int noteTiming = noteTimings[i];
    float notePosition = (noteTiming-currentTime) / scrollSpeed;
}
```

The note position will be a value, 1 meaning the note is at the top of the screen and 0 at the bottom where the player should hit it.

**What I want to do**

I want to make a multiplier that will multiply the speed of the notes. With the actual code multiplying the note speed while playing will make the notes jump, for example if I multiply the note speed by two the notes will have the double of separation than before, and that would look like the notes moved INSTANTLY, but I want that double separation to be done before changing the speed so it looks linear and well when playing

edit: here's an example of how I want it to look: https://youtube.com/watch?v=ZBtNjb8E1n4
As you can see it changes velocity, this is done by changing the timing points so the velocity slow down or speed up depending on a multiplier

Answer (score 1):

Each note needs a velocity property, which is responsible for moving the note by a given amount on each frame.

The note has a direction of travel, the y axis, let's calls this `vy`
Its current position on any given frame is `y`, so the speed of the note is:

`y += vy`

Then, on each frame of the animation you need to alter the speed (the distance the note moves in one frame) of the note.

You can do this by assigning an acceleration a property to each note. e.g. `acceleration = 0.125` where the value represents the number of pixels you want to accelerate/decelerate by per frame.

Then, if you add acceleration to the direction on each frame:

`vx += acceleration`

and then add this to the note's position

`y += vy`

The note will accelerate in a linear manner.

I don't program in `C#` but here's the code in JavaScript running on the `x` axis rather than the `y`. The bit you want is in the loop:

```
// move and accelerate the shape
  // if the shape hasn't reached the end of the canvas
  if (x <= canvas.width + 16) {
    vx += acceleration; // add accelaration to the velocity
    x += vx; // move the shape with the new velocity value
  } else {
    // the shape reached the end of the canvas
    vx = 0; // reset the velocity
    x = 0; // repostion the shape at the begining of the canvas
  }
```

```js
// A canvas element for the animation
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); // we draw on the context
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#555";
canvas.height = 100;

// **** Canvas Animation **** \\
// some vars to help us move something on canvas
let x = 0,
  vx = 1, // velocity
  acceleration = 0.125; // acceleration

// A loop so that we can animate something on the canvas
loop();
function loop() {
  // loop the animation at 60fps
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
  // fill the width of the page with the canvas
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;

  // clear the canvas so we can redraw everyframe
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // draw a shape on the canvas
  ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, 16, 16, canvas.height - 35);
  ctx.fill();

  // move and accelerate the shape
  // if the shape hasn't reached the end of the canvas
  if (x <= canvas.width + 16) {
    vx += acceleration; // add accelaration to the velocity
    x += vx; // move the shape with the new velocity value
  } else {
    // the shape reached the end of the canvas
    vx = 0; // reset the velocity
    x = 0; // repostion the shape at the begining of the canvas
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(28, 26, 26);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

If you wanted to accelerate in a non-linear manner, you would just need to implement an easing algorithm.

**Note:** In the above example, we are just painting pixels, where the top left corner of the shape is at `x, y`. At the start of each new frame, we clear the canvas and start to repaint the shape at a new `x` position which is calculated as `vx + acceleration` and then incrementing the value of `x` by `x += vx` thus, we are setting this speed and acceleration globally. We are not able to assign any properties to this shape because it does not exist as an object, its just a load of pixels!

If, as I presume (I can't make any comments to ask questions at the moment, as I am new to this site) you want to alter the speed and acceleration of individual notes, I would make the shape, or note as an object that I can assign properties to. Then you can tweak the property values with your game logic.

e.g. using JavaScript, I may have a note object that has properties like these:

```
let note = {
  // physical dimensions and position of circle center
  radius: 16,
  x: 16,
  y: 16,

  // styling props
  fillColor: "blue",
  lineColor: "black",

  // physics props
  vx: 0, // velocity in x direction
  vy: 0, // velocity in y direction
  acc: 0, // acceleration
  friction: 1, // friction
};
```

then in our set up, we can set the objects properties as desired

```
// set up
note.vy = 1;
note.acc = 0.125;
```

and then in our game loop we can use game logic to move the note as and when we want

````
// the animation loop
function gameLoop() {
    // function to ask the browser to repaint the screen / canvas
  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

  // **** game logic here **** \\
  if (a condition is true)
  // increment the values in each new frame
  note.vy += note.acc; // increment the velocity by acceleration
  note.y += note.vy; // increment the note's position by the velocity
}
```
````